# PERCENTAGE USING TWO DIFFERENT COLUMNS, USING GROUP BY IN SUBQUERY

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, percentage

1. I alreADY written a code for it but, there is no response, i am using postgreSQL.
2. The final thing i want is to find THE ERROR PERCENTAGE STATUS(see the status colounm which have 200 Ok or not found) FOR EACH DAY.

   FOR EG-- 2016/07/22 - 1.5% ERROR

   P.S the database is really big with different status and dates, i want 
   result date wise
3. In above code i am trying to find the (NOT-FOUND status/Total Status) for each day

THE code is  :-

```
SELECT status, date(time), round(coun/total) AS percent
FROM log,

(SELECT count(*) AS coun
FROM log 
WHERE status NOT LIKE '200 OK'
GROUP BY date(time) 
ORDER BY date(time)) c, 


(SELECT  count(*) AS total
FROM log GROUP BY  
date(time) 
ORDER BY date(time)) t 


GROUP BY date(time), status, percent
ORDER BY date(time);
```

The database i have is like that...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmiqd.jpg)

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: Are you joining on the `subqueries` in the implied joins? I'm not `postgresql`, but why can't you take the `subqueries` and put them inside your `round()` or better still put them into variables above the `Select` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct status, date(time), round(count(1) over (partition by date(time))/count(1) over ()) AS percent, count(1) over (partition by date(time)), count(1) over ()
FROM log
```

it would give you percentage for statuses per day. not only not 200, but all, which would make more sense because you dont filter it in general query.

or you can add `FILTER (where status NOT LIKE '200 OK')` before over for count if you still want it.

but general idea is not to scan same table three times and not join the result...